# How to apply a Coq hypothesis of the form A = B -> C = D to a subgoal of the form A = B

Tags: coq

I'm working on a proof and I'm currently stuck at this. I have a hypothesis which reads:

```
T1E : tree1 = EmptyTree -> isEmpty (leftChild (Node tree1 tree2)) = true
```

I also have a hypothesis:

```
H2 : isEmpty (leftChild (Node tree1 tree2)) = true
```

and my current sub-goal is

```
tree1 = EmptyTree
```

It seems like I should be able to do

```
rewrite <- T1E
```

in order to change the subgoal to

```
isEmpty (leftChild (Node tree1 tree2)) = true
```

but when I try that, Coq says

```
Error: Found no subterm matching "true" in the current goal.
```

How can I prove my current subgoal using T1E and H2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not going to be able to prove your goal using `T1E`. Essentially, you're trying to prove `A` knowing that "if `A` is true, then `B` is true`.

However, looking at your context, it seems to me that you should be able to simplify in `H2` and get either a contradiction or more information on `tree1`, which in any case should result in what you want.

Comment: I definitely wasn't thinking about that carefully. For some reason I have a tendency to think of P->Q in coq as rewriting rules rather than implication, which works if tree1 = EmptyTree is another hypothesis, but obviously doesn't work if it is a goal. Thanks for the reminder =D.